# Access this in prototype function after a callback

Tags: javascript

I have following code :

```
function A() {
  this.value = 'a_value';
}

A.prototype.getValue = function(){
   console.log(this.value); // got undefined, expected 'a_value'
}

setTimeout(new A().getValue, 100);
```

why i get `this.value` as undefined.?
and how how do i access `this.value`?

EDIT : i am not allowed to change the `setTimeout` line (last line) of code.

Comment: that means just `calling`, not `callback`.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: have you tried `console.log(this);`?

> You are only passing the `getValue` function to `setTimeout`, not its context. Something like this would work: `setTimeout(function() {new A().getValue();},100);` But without changing that last line, there's basically nothing you can do.

Comment: this is `window`. Are you really sure?, there any other way to solve problem, without changing the last line.

Comment: basically i just don't want to manually call `getValue` function. i just want to get it called automatically somehow after passing `getValue` as a callback.

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid using the `this` altogether and not having this kind of problems with the following technique :

```
var A = function () { // no new no this
    var value = 'a_value';
    var getValue = function(){
        console.log(value);
    };
    return Object.freeze({
        getValue ,
    });
};

setTimeout(A().getValue, 100);
```

or write

```
var a = new A();
```

before, and then

```
setTimeout(a.getValue.bind(a), 100);
```

Comment: i tried and not worked

Comment: @HMR his comment is outdated because I edited my answer.